# ¿Oracle 11g guarda la fecha de los insert realizados?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

Tengo una tabla como la siguiente en oracle:

```
SELECT * FROM ESTUDIANTES;

ID   NOMBRE   EDAD
--   ------   ----
1    Pepe     23
2    Maria    35
...
```

¿Puedo averiguar de alguna manera en que fecha se hicieron los insert en esa tabla?

Comment: mira en la tabla sys.dba_objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La respuesta es **NO**. Si quieres la fecha de INSERT, tienes que agregar una columna fecha a la definición de la tabla con ese propósito y mantener esta información tu mismo.

En otra respuesta se sugiere usar la pseudo-columna especial `ORA_ROW_SCN` combinado con la función `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP`. La idea es interesante, pero tiene 2 problemas importantes:

1. `ORA_ROW_SCN` devuelve un número que es el *system change number* (SCN), que representa *la última vez que cambió el registro*. O sea que a cada vez que un `UPDATE` modifica un registro, el `ORA_ROW_SCN` cambia, de modo que se pierde la información de cuando ocurrió el `INSERT`.
2. Aún si no cambiara el registro después de ser insertado, después de un tiempo indeterminado, el tratar de usar `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` para convertir el valor `ORA_ROWSCN` a una fecha no va a funcionar y te va a dar un error (*no snapshot found based on specified time*). Esto es porque la información de fecha está conservada en el REDO de Oracle, que es un archivo que es continualmente reescrito, y no guarda la información de forma permanente.

Por estas 2 razones, evita usar `ORA_ROWSCN` + `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP`, porque aunque parezca funcionar a primera vista, si le haces un `UPDATE` a los registros o si esperas suficiente tiempo, verás que ya no funcionará.

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza [ORA_ROWSCN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm)

```
SELECT ORA_ROWSCN, ID, NOMBRE, EDAD FROM ESTUDIANTES;

SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN), ID, NOMBRE, EDAD FROM ESTUDIANTES;
```

Comment: Flowen Como ha dicho @sstan ORA_ROWSCN se modifica con el tiempo, lo acabo de comprobar, gracias.